# Using .NET Clipboard in ASP.NEt WebForms app

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, clipboard

I need to copy data from `Webform` to clipboard. But standard `System.Windows.Forms.Clipdoard` doesn't work, and it's expectable.

I've found solution with JS, but it'll be better to use code-behind.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to copy some data to user's clipboard, so you'll need to use some JS solution.

A good one is [ZeroClipboard](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard). Is same solution used by GitHub site to copy "HTTPS clone URL" to user clipboard.